# How to combine columns into a new table - Python or R

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

Scenario:

If I have this table, let's call it `df`:

| survey_answer_1___1 | survey_answer_1___2 | survey_answer_1___3 | survey_answer_2___1 | survey_answer_2___2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Using R or Python, how do I split and transform `df` into `survey_answer_1` and `survey_answer_2` like this:

`survey_answer_1`:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

`survey_answer_2`:

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |

Where the column names of the new tables are extracted from `df` column names after `'___'`. The values in the new cells is the count of 1s in each column in `df`. This should be done automatically (tables should not be "hard-coded"), as there are many other columns in my data file that this should be applied on as well.

`split()` can be used to extract the numbers after `'___'` for column names. I tried implementing the rest using a dictionary, but it is not working.

Comment: `x <- colSums(df); split(setNames(x, gsub('(\\d+)$|.', '\\1', names(x))), gsub('_{2,}\\d+', '', names(x)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using R / tidyverse, first `dplyr::summarize()` all columns to sums; then `tidyr::pivot_longer()`; then `split()` by `survey_answer`; then `purrr::map()` over the resulting list to drop all-`NA` columns :

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

survey_dfs <- df %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), sum)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(), 
    names_to = c("survey_answer", ".value"), 
    names_sep = "___"
  ) %>% 
  split(.$survey_answer, drop = TRUE) %>% 
  map(\(d) select(d, where(\(col) !all(is.na(col))) & !survey_answer))

survey_dfs
```

```r
$survey_answer_1
# A tibble: 1 × 3
    `1`   `2`   `3`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     3     1

$survey_answer_2
# A tibble: 1 × 2
    `1`   `2`
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     0
```

This gives you a named list of dataframes, [which is best practice in most cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/17303805). If you really want the resulting dataframes loose in the global environment, you can replace the `map()` call with an `assign()` call within `purrr::iwalk()`:

```
df %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), sum)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(), 
    names_to = c("survey_answer", ".value"), 
    names_sep = "___"
  ) %>% 
  split(.$survey_answer, drop = TRUE) %>% 
  iwalk(\(d, dname) {
    d <- select(d, where(\(col) !all(is.na(col))) & !survey_answer)
    assign(dname, d, pos = 1)
  })

survey_answer_1
```

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
    `1`   `2`   `3`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     3     1
```

Comment: What does the \ in `map(\(d)` do? Your code seems to works except for the drop `NA` columns?

Comment: `\(x)` is anonymous function shorthand in R -- it's equivalent to `lambda x:` in Python. The code seems to drop `NA` columns with your example data; can you update your question with data that reproduces the problem you're having?

Comment: I'm unfortunately unable to provide actual data, but the error is: "unexpected input..." and the arrow (`^`) points at the \

Comment: What version of R are you using? The `\()` shorthand was introduced in 4.1.0. You could update, or change to the longhand version, i.e., `function(d)` instead of `\(d)`, and the same for `\(col)`.

Comment: Thank you, I did the change and it works perfectly! I'm using version 4.0.x

Answer (score 3):

Here an R example where the new columns can be arbitrary values

```r
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0), 4, 5, dim=list(
  1:4, paste0("survey_answer_", c(1,1,1,2,2), "__", c(1,2,3,1,5)) )))

df 
#>   survey_answer_1__1 survey_answer_1__2 survey_answer_1__3 survey_answer_2__1
#> 1                  1                  1                  0                  1
#> 2                  0                  1                  0                  0
#> 3                  0                  0                  0                  1
#> 4                  1                  1                  1                  0
#>   survey_answer_2__5
#> 1                  0
#> 2                  0
#> 3                  0
#> 4                  0

var <- Map(c, names(df), strsplit(names(df), "__"))

result <- tapply(var, sapply(var,"[", 2), \(x) 
       setNames(colSums(df[sapply(x,"[",1)]) , sapply(x,"[",3)))

#to assign the resuilt list to new  datafrae variables:
list2env(result, environment())


survey_answer_1
#> 1 2 3 
#> 2 3 1
survey_answer_2
#> 1 5 
#> 2 0
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a column to each table that subtracts row sum from 500 (500 - sum of values in row)?

Comment: The results are vectors, so to convert to data frame and add 500-sum column you can do: `result <- tapply(var, sapply(var,"[", 2), \(x) 
 setNames(colSums(df[sapply(x,"[",1)]) , sapply(x,"[",3))) |> lapply(\(x)
 data.frame(as.list(c(x, "500 - sum" = sum(x))), check.names = F ))
`

Answer (score 0):

For answer 1, you could do the following:

```py
# grab correct columns
df_answer_1 = df[[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('survey_answer_1')]] 

# change column names
df_answer_1.columns = [col[-1] for col in df_answer_1.columns]

# sum up columns
answer_1_sums = df_answer_1.sum()
```

You can do the same for answer 2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is in `csv`:

```
survey_answer_1___1,survey_answer_1___2,survey_answer_1___3,survey_answer_2___1,survey_answer_2___2
1,1,0,1,0
0,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0
1,1,1,0,0
```

Read data:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    df = [row for row in reader]
```

Process data:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

dd = defaultdict(Counter)
for row in df:
    for k, v in row.items():
        key1, key2 = k.split('___')
        dd[key1][int(key2)] += int(v)
```

Print result:

```
for k in dd:
    print(k, sorted(dd[k].items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
# raw data
df = {"survey_answer_1___1":[1,0,0,1], "survey_answer_1___2":[1,1,0,1], "survey_answer_1___3":[0,0,0,1], "survey_answer_2___1":[1,0,1,0], "survey_answer_2___2":[0,0,0,0]}
# sum up the answers
for k in df:
    sum_df[k] = sum(df[k])
# extract answer_1
survey_answer_1 = {[k[-1]:sum_df[k] for k in sum_df if k.startswith("survey_answer_1")]}
survey_answer_1
{'1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 1}
# extract answer_2
survey_answer_2 = {k[-1]:sum_df[k] for k in sum_df if k.startswith("survey_answer_2")}
survey_answer_2
{'1': 2, '2': 0}
```